# How to use cbc mode in javascript using AES

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, aes, padding

I want to use CBC mode encryption for the message using AES algorithm (AES code is available) 
in javascript.
How can this be done?
I am new to cryptography and javascript.
Generating key & IV,  padding, taking care of padding while decrypting are the issues to be handled.
How to get started with this?

Comment: I removed the `cbc-mac` tag. CBC-MAC is a Message Authentication Code. It's based on CBC, but it's not directly related to your question.

Comment: You have already learned, why (http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/) cryptography in JavaScript is useless, haven't you?

Comment: Here's how to get started: http://www.google.com/search?q=aes+javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you start by reading [NIST: Recommendation for Block Cipher Modes of Operation](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf).

It covers CBC, padding and how to generate IVs.

On a side-note:

You may want to start with Counter Mode (also covered in the recommendation). It's by far easier to understand and implement. You don't need any padding and you don't need a separate function for decryption. Encryption and decryption are basically the same thing in Counter Mode.